# Having trouble with return variable scope in java

Tags: java

I want to return a String/StringBuilder of a large letter E that is filled in with E's such that I get something like this:

EEEEEE
   E
   E
   E
   EEEEEE
   E
   E
   E
   EEEEEE

The issue I am having right now is that I have a StringBuilder value, `sb`, that should be getting updated during the nested for loop. What do I have to do to have my function `drawLetters` return `sb` so that I can print it in my `main()` function?

The error I get is `drawLetters` is missing a return statement. I tried to move the `sb` outside of the for loop, but then the for loop doesn't update the variable because it is outside of the for loop scope.

tl;dr - confused about scope and where the `sb` variable should go so that my function `drawLetters`returns `sb`

```
public class MCVE {

    public static String drawLetters(String string) {
        // Create BufferedImage object called "background".
        BufferedImage background = new BufferedImage(144, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // Creates a Graphics2D object called "g" by calling the method get.Graphics() on the background
        Graphics g = background.getGraphics();

        // This decides what is drawn.
        g.drawString(string, 6, 12);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 144; x++)
                sb.append(background.getRGB(x, y) == -16777216 ? " " : background.getRGB(x, y) == -1 ? string : "*");
            if (sb.toString().trim().isEmpty())
                continue;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(drawLetters("E"));
        //drawLetters("J");
        //drawLetters("K");
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare `sb` outside of the loop if you plan to return it outside of the loop

Comment: You forgot block braces for your for-loop. The if-statement seems to be intended to be inside the loop.

Comment: If `sb.toString().trim().isEmpty()` is always true, the `return` will never be reached. I'm not sure what the potential for that happening is.

Comment: And change method to return String and do `return sb.toString();`, it makes more sense to return the actual value

Comment: The compiler complains of a missing return statement because of cases where your return might never be reached, in the view of the compiler.

Comment: I made the changes, but when I run it, i get a blank output

Answer (score 2):

You declare `sb` inside the loop:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //...
} //Scope of sb ends here
```

So it is out of scope outisde of the outer for loop. Right now you are trying to return it inside the `for` loop, which works, but isn't what you want. Declare it outside of the loop:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++) {        
    for (int x = 0; x < 144; x++)
        sb.append(background.getRGB(x, y) == -16777216 ? " " : background.getRGB(x, y) == -1 ? string : "*");
    if (sb.toString().trim().isEmpty()) 
        continue;        
}
return sb;
```

Also if you want to print `sb`, use the `toString()` method, and do it before you return; otherwise it is an unreachable statement.

If I were you, I would return a `String`, and not a `StringBuilder`. Otherwise everytime you call the method and try to print it you will have to add in a `toString()` call. You can change your method signature to:

```
public static String drawLetters(String string)
```

And then in your return statement

```
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: I made the changes, but did I do something wrong still? Nothing is printing out

Comment: @EvanKim Your code has the possibility to return an empty `String`. I would debug to see what it is returning